# postgres 9.4 hangs when starting as service during centos 6.9 boot

Tags: centos6, postgresql

postgres 9.4 hangs when starting as service during centos 6.9 boot.
The server was running well for months, and then we perform a restart and it hangs on starting postgres 9.4 as a service. The disks have still plenty of space, no checkdisk errors...

When I start it manually, I do get the attached output, but I can't see what is the problem. how can find the cause of the problem?
Manual start (as user postgres):

> [/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/postgres -d 5 -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvGcn.png)

I also started it in single user mode, but don't know very well how to use/fix the problem. Please some help?